# Outlook on-send add-in manifest file works when sideloading, fails validation when admins use Integrated Apps

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have a JavaScript Outlook on-send add-in (not Smart Alerts) that has recently been updated and published.  The add-in is hosted on an Azure Storage Blob.

When Exchange admins go to remove the add-in, then re-add it using Integrated Apps, and follow the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide, there is an error that says that the manifest file has failed:

[Integrated Apps Failed Validation Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ofG.png)

How can we correct this problem?

Our manifest file is located at https://addins.sperrysoftware365.com/prd-addins/SafeguardSend/manifest.xml?ver=3.2

Why does it work when sideloading it into Outlook but not work when admins deploy it through Integrated Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose they do the same check as the store does. Try to run the following command to validate the manifest file on your machine:

```
npx office-addin-manifest validate -p MANIFEST_FILE
```

The `office-addin-manifest` package/tool calls a service endpoint (which is also used by the store) and just report the results.

Comment: Thanks Eugene!  It definitely is failing and we can now address it.  How often are developers expected to validate their manifests?  Is there a site/blog that tells us when Microsoft updates the manifest validation process?

Comment: There is no such information.

Comment: Mysteriously, today we tested again and the same manifest, without any modifications, now works.  An interesting side note is that the same manifest file worked to deploy in Exchange Admin Center; it was only the Microsoft Admin Center Integrated Apps that was broken for a brief time.

Comment: Sounds like something has been changed on the Exchange/O365 side.